# opposite image width 100% and height auto and not want to scroll top to bottom in css

Tags: css

```
img
{
width:100%;
height:auto;
}
```

I want to fix the image height according the device. no scroll required, like image width 2000px and height 1500px;

Answer (score 0):

For CSS only, one method would be to set up media queries with static values for viewport widths. You can include as many as you want and there is a lot of information online about typical device widths. For example:

```
img { height: 1500px; width: 2000px; }
@media (max-height:520px) {
    img { width: 693px; height: 520px; }
}
@media (max-height:515px) {
    img { width: 686px; height: 515px; }
}
@media (max-height:510px) {
    img { width: 680px; height: 510px; }
}
@media (max-height:505px) {
    img { width: 673px; height: 505px; }
}
@media (max-height:500px) {
    img { width: 666px; height: 500px; }
}
/* ... and so on ... */
```

That method is useful if you are strictly using css, but it requires manual configuration of device width thresholds.

If you are open to using Javascript or jQuery, the changes to the image dimensions can happen automatically depending on the size of the window, even if it is resized.

Here is a working example of JS/jQuery that resizes the image depending on the window size:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

window.onresize = function(event) {

if($(window).height() < $(window).width()){
// adjust according to device height
    var $windowheight = $(window).height();
    var $origheight = parseInt($('img').css('height'));
    var $diff = $windowheight/$origheight;
    var $origwidth = parseInt($('img').css('width'));
    var $newwidth = $origwidth * $diff;
    console.log("h: "+$windowheight+" w: "+$newwidth);
    $('img').css('height',$windowheight);
    $('img').css('width',$newwidth);
}else{
// adjust according to device width
    var $windowwidth = $(window).width();
    var $origwidth = parseInt($('img').css('width'));
    var $diff = $windowwidth/$origwidth;
    var $origheight = parseInt($('img').css('height'));
    var $newheight = $origheight * $diff;
    console.log("h: "+$newheight+" w: "+$windowwidth);
    $('img').css('height',$newheight);
    $('img').css('width',$windowwidth);
}

}

});
```

That example uses very messy code, as I just threw it together on the fly, but it works. It can certainly use some improvements, however.

[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/JqUGG/)